# PostgreSQL imbalanced index query optimization

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, index-tuning

I am having performance issues with my query because the index is heavily imbalanced. I have a column `family_id` on a table. The table has about 150 million records. This `family_id` column identifies which records inside the table belong to the same family. A family has, on average, ~5 members. However, because of the data is not clean, there exist edge cases in our data where the `family_id` is `NULL` (~600.000 records) or where the `family_id` is `-1` (~3.2 million records).

I am building a data pipeline in Logstash which queries this data and incrementally forwards it to a Elasticsearch index. For my use case, I need to bring the data on a per family basis. The case where `family_id` is `-1` or `NULL` requires special treatment, and therefore I need to filter based on that. However, such queries take extremely long for a batch of 10.000 records. To give an idea of the time difference; the normal case takes about 10-20 seconds, whereas the `-1` or `NULL` case takes about 30 minutes.

Is there a proper solution for such cases such that I can speed up this query?

Thanks!

**Query and DDL**
As requested I have added the table DDL, query and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. The table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "xml".t_patent_document_values (
    patent_document_value_id serial4 NOT NULL,
    publication_id int4 NOT NULL,
    ucid varchar(32) NULL,
    lang bpchar(2) NULL,
    country bpchar(2) NULL,
    doc_number varchar(32) NULL,
    kind varchar(4) NULL,
    published date NULL,
    produced date NULL,
    withdraw bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    family_id int4 NULL,
    status varchar(16) NULL,
    modified_load_id int4 NOT NULL,
    created_load_id int4 NULL,
    deleted_load_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT t_patent_document_values_pkey PRIMARY KEY (patent_document_value_id)
);
CREATE INDEX family_id_publication_id_idx ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (family_id, publication_id) WHERE (family_id = '-1'::integer);
CREATE INDEX family_id_publication_id_null_idx ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (family_id, publication_id) WHERE ((family_id IS NULL) AND (publication_id > 0));
CREATE INDEX idx_country_published ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (country, published);
CREATE INDEX idx_created_load_id ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (created_load_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_created_load_id_modified_load_id ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (created_load_id, modified_load_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_created_load_id_modified_load_id_family_id ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (created_load_id, modified_load_id, family_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_ctry_dnum ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (country, doc_number);
CREATE INDEX idx_family_id ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (family_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_modified_load_id ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (modified_load_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_patent_document_publication_id ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (publication_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_patent_document_published ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (published);
CREATE INDEX idx_patent_document_ucid ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (ucid);
CREATE INDEX idx_patent_document_values_country ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (country);
CREATE INDEX idx_published_month ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (date_part('month'::text, published));
CREATE INDEX idx_published_year ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (date_part('year'::text, published));
CREATE INDEX idx_t_patent_document_values_cmp ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (publication_id, modified_load_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_withdrawn ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (withdraw);
```

The fast query (`family_id != -1 or family_id is not null`):

```
select array_agg(tpdv.publication_id)
from 
    xml.t_patent_document_values tpdv 
where 
    tpdv.family_id > 0
group by tpdv.family_id
order by tpdv.family_id
limit 1000
```

Its `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Limit  (cost=0.57..20178.18 rows=1000 width=36) (actual time=0.017..16.191 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.57..473243036.65 rows=23453864 width=36) (actual time=0.016..16.123 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Group Key: family_id
        ->  Index Scan using idx_family_id on t_patent_document_values tpdv  (cost=0.57..472220861.17 rows=145800436 width=8) (actual time=0.012..15.608 rows=1002 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (family_id > 0)
Planning time: 0.323 ms
Execution time: 16.259 ms
```

Note that in reality this query will do a lot more aggregations over the `family_id`, but this is a simplified version such that the problem might be easier to tackle.

The slow query:

```
select *
from 
    xml.t_patent_document_values tpdv 
    where (tpdv.family_id = -1 or tpdv.family_id is null) and publication_id > 0
order by publication_id
limit 1000
```

Its `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Limit  (cost=0.57..122889.16 rows=1000 width=73) (actual time=52632.236..1731648.507 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using idx_patent_document_publication_id on t_patent_document_values tpdv  (cost=0.57..484776575.75 rows=3944846 width=73) (actual time=52632.235..1731648.326 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (publication_id > 0)
        Filter: ((family_id = '-1'::integer) OR (family_id IS NULL))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 27646323
Planning time: 3.102 ms
Execution time: 1731657.620 ms
```

Comment: Please add the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for both the slow and fast query. Also please provide the query itself, and the table / index structures. It doesn't sound like a data balancing problem, as far as indexes are concerned. It may be an index definition problem though.

Comment: I have updated the question as per your request.

Comment: From what I have noticed so far, it seems that the main issue arises with the OR condition. If I split up the queries in one part `family_id=-1` and one part `family_id is null` it seems to be fast.

Comment: Your plan doesn't match your query.

Comment: You might have a problem, but this doesn't seem like a real description of it.  Why do you want to process the same 1000 rows over and over again?

Comment: Please show the plans for the split up queries which perform better.

Comment: I do not need to process the same 1000 rows over and over again. This is just an example. The 0 values in `family_id > 0` and `publication_id > 0`, will change to the last value of the previous batch of 1000, such that all data is processed in batches. If interested here is some background: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-getting-started-search-use-cases-db-logstash.html. Basically, the value will be `:sql_last_value` in Logstash.

Comment: I will recheck the plans if I did not accidentally pasted the wrong one. The one of the slow query takes a long time though, so will add it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The fast query is fast because it can use the index `idx_family_id` for both the GROUP BY and the ORDER BY, so it can scan the index for the first 1000 `family_id` and then stop because of the LIMIT 1000.

The slow query needs to use two indexes, `family_id_publication_id_idx` and `idx_family_id`, to satisfy both conditions in the OR, so it needs to read all 1314953 rows, before sorting them by publication_id and keeping only the first 1000.

To speed up that query you need a single index which satisfies both OR conditions in the WHERE and having publication_id as the first column, to satisfy the ORDER BY.

Try with this:

```
CREATE INDEX publication_id_family_id_null_or_neg_idx ON xml.t_patent_document_values USING btree (publication_id, family_id) WHERE ((family_id IS NULL or family_id = -1) AND (publication_id > 0));
```

Using this index, Postresql will just have to scan the first 1000 rows of the index and they will already be in the needed order, so it can stop for the LIMIT.